# Retrieving specific value from CSV layer to use in QGIS Expressions when conditions match current Atlas feature

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression, atlas

I have configured an Atlas which is tied to a "ref_pln" column in a coverage layer. I also have a CSV layer with the columns "ref_pln", "attribute" and "value".

I'd like to pull the value of "value" for a specific value of an "attribute" in the CSV layer whenever its "ref_pln" matches the "ref_pln" currently being displayed in the Atlas.

Example:

- Atlas "ref_pln" is currently "003";
- The attribute I want to pull is "date";
- My CSV layer has the following records:

RECORDS:

```
ref_pln | attribute | value

002     | issue     | yes
002     | solved    | no
002     | date      | 1500
003     | issue     | yes
003     | solved    | no
003     | date      | 1250
```

I'd like to build an expression which displays "1250" (i.e. the value of "value" when the value of "attribute" is "date" and the value of "ref_pln" is "003" - i.e. the same as the Atlas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's possible to do it like I wanted (using Expressions to query data) but managed to do it in another way.

Fist, I have filtered the CSV layer to show only features with "date" as value for "attribute".

Then using the following expression

```
attribute(get_feature('CSV_LAYER','ref_pln', attribute(@atlas_feature,'ref_pln')),'val')
```

will get the right value. But still interested in an expressions-only solution if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
if("ref_pln" = attribute(@atlas_feature,"ref_pln") AND "attribute" = 'date', "value", 'Nope.')
```

- will return the value of `"value"` when both of these conditions are true:

  1. the `"ref_pln"` value of the current feature matches the `"ref_pln"` value of the current atlas feature
  2. the `"attribute"` value of the current feature is date
- if those two conditions are not both true, it will return the string `Nope.`

Feel free to substitute any other string or outcome for the `Nope.` string.

---

Note: Having your attributes called "attribute" and "value" is extremely confusing. Writing this expression was like being the straightman in the comedy sketch ["Who's on First?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTcRRaXV-fg). It would be less confusing if you named the fields "attrib" and "val", just so they don't have exactly the same names as existing terms.

Comment: Thanks, still not there since I need something like ---  if("ref_pln" [of map layer "XXX"] = attribute(@atlas_feature,"ref_pln") AND "attribute" [of map layer "XXX"] = 'date', "value" [of map layer "XXX"] , 'Nope.') --- but I am trying to figure it out.